# Dynamically update marker

Tags: highcharts

How to plot a marker values on a series.I have x and y axis values in an array.

```
chart.series[0].setData(marker_points,true);
```

My Fiddle:-

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j06szr0/)

Comment: That code should work, unless you have specific options somewhere set (like disabled marker). Could you setup jsFiddle demo?

Comment: Your code is working but you didn't add jQuery and Highcharts js files to your fiddle. Updated for you: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j06szr0/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please post it as answer so that i can accept the answer as well.